# ruby rspec and strings comparison

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm not a ruby expert and may be this will seem a silly question...but I'm too courious about an oddity (I think) I've found in RSpec matcher called match.

You know `match` takes in input a string or a regex. Example:

```
"test".should match "test" #=> will pass
"test".should match /test/ #=> will pass
```

The strange begins when you insert special regex characters in the input string:

```
"*test*".should match "*test*" #=> will fail throwing a regex exception
```

This means (I thought) that input strings are interpreted as regex, then I should escape special regex characters to make it works:

```
"*test*".should match "\*test\*" #=> will fail with same exception
"*test*".should match /\*test\*/ #=> will pass
```

From this basic test, I understand that `match` treats input strings as regular expressions but it does not allow you to escape special regex characters.

Am I true? Is not this a singular behavior? I mean, it's a string or a regex!

---

EDIT AFTER ANSWER:

Following DigitalRoss (right) answer the following tests passed:

```
"*test*".should match "\\*test\\*" #=> pass
"*test*".should match '\*test\*' #=> pass
"*test*".should match /\*test\*/ #=> pass
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you are seeing is the different interpretation of backslash-escaped characters in String vs Regexp. In a soft (") quoted string, `\*` becomes a `*`, but `/\*/` is really a backslash followed by a star.

If you use hard quotes (') for the String objects *or* double the backslash characters (only for the Strings, though) then your tests should produce the same results.

Comment: Thanks you are right. I edited the question with the code tests you mentioned.

Comment: You can also escape regexp like strings, e.g.
  %r{\\*test\\*}
Not so useful with this because you still need backslashes, but found it invaluable when matching for /

Comment: lightly related, but i ran into a similar issue - mine was around string comparisons containing escaped characters, `\nsome text\n' for example. fixed using double quotes to prevent rspec from double escaping.